# Relation between one touch and binary option

Tags: options, option-pricing, binary-options

Is there a relation between the price of a one touch option and the price of a binary option?

By one touch option, I mean an option that pays off a fixed amount if the price of the underlying is above a certain threshold at any point in time before or at maturity.

By binary option, I mean an option that pays off a fixed amount if the price of the underlying is above a certain threshold at maturity.

Answer (score 1):

The One Touch option is approximately twice the price of the equivalent Binary Option. This result can be shown to be exact if the underlying process is a pure Wiener process using the Reflection Principal. For lognormal processes this result is a good approximation but not exact.

Answer (score -3):

One touch option is an American barrier digital